# Video converter for the PlayStation Portable

Tags: video-conversion

I've tried various video converters for the PlayStation Portable

Software I have tried so far:

- *Free Make* is good, but the output format makes the video lag.
- *Total Video Converter* is also good, but it will take you about 15 minutes, just by setting up the videos if you want to convert lots of files. Because you will need to rename it (the default name of the output video is not very descriptive), it takes extra time.
- *Miro* video converters output doesn't play on psp.
- *PSP Video 9*. Not good enough.
- *xvid AVI-converter* takes too long time to convert.

Does anyone have any better suggestions for video transcoding software for the PSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule number one about video conversion: it takes a long time.  Adding more hardware resources to the operation (RAM, processor, etc) can speed it up, but video converting is still going to be one of the slowest operations a regular computer user can perform.

With that said, have you tried using [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)? Their forums have plenty of threads related to converting and ripping for PSP playback.